# How do I make a Lua function return key,pairs to a yet unpopulated table?

Tags: lua, indexing, lua-table

I want the key pairs to be tableToPopulate.width = 30 and tableToPopulate.Height = 20
They are currently tableToPopulate[1] = 30 and tableToPopulate[2] = 20

---

```
local function X ()
    code, code...
    return 30,20
end

local tableToPopulate = {
    x()
}
```

Comment: how's this related to [tag:ios] or [tag:iphone]?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just return a table?

```
local function X ()
    return {width=30, height=20}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in the table you want the values set on, like this:

```
function x(tbl)
    tbl.Height = 20; 
    tbl.Width = 30;
end

local t={}
x(t)
print(t.Height, t.Width)
```

although it may make more sense to use nested tables depending on how complex the structure will be of whatever is in the table.

```
function x(tbl)
    table.insert(tbl, {Height = 20, Width = 30})
end

local t={}
x(t)
print(t[1].Height, t[1].Width)
```

which would be equivalent to this:

```
function x()
    return {Height = 20, Width = 30}
end
local t = {x()}
print(t[1].Height, t[1].Width)
```

So really, it depends on how you want to group the data and which syntax you prefer.